# ActionBarActivity cannot resolve

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the error `"Cannot resolve the symbol ActionBarActivity"` when I try to import it .

I read questions about the same problem and read the answers and tried to solve the problem but to no avail.

I'm using android studio version 3.2.1.0

This is my build gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

MainActivity file:

```
package com.example.android.justjava;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        display(1);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
                R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Cannot resolve the symbol ActionBarActivity"

This is because `ActionBarActivity` is already deprecated and has been removed in the recent support libraries.

You need to migrate from `ActionBarActivity` and use [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity).